# Graph API denies access even though I granted access

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I followed the ASP.NET [Quick Start guide](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) and got the project working.

The API succeeds in retrieving my email address just fine - great.

Now I want to get a list of users and retrieve some of their properties.

In `GraphService`:

```
public async Task GetUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{
    var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("mail").GetAsync();
}
```

Which I call with (copying the method to retrieve user email):

```
var graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();

await graphService.GetUsers(graphClient);
```

But I get an error

> {Code: Authorization_RequestDeniedMessage: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.Inner error}

Even though I set these privelages:

[image]

Why must this be so difficult? I am connecting to the API and getting my own email address, but I can't do anything else...

When I run `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` in the Graph Explorer it returns all the users just fine...

Please someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to [this sample application](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample), then i want to mention to acquire *access token* it utilizes [`ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.iclientapplicationbase.acquiretokensilentasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_IClientApplicationBase_AcquireTokenSilentAsync_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__Microsoft_Identity_Client_IUser_) which accepts as a first parameter *the list of scopes requested for resource*. Those scopes (delegated permissions) are specified in [`web.config`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample/blob/master/Microsoft%20Graph%20SDK%20ASPNET%20Connect/Microsoft%20Graph%20SDK%20ASPNET%20Connect/Web.config#L15) file via `ida:GraphScopes` key. In another words, no matter what permissions have been granted via app registration, access token will be requested per scopes specified via `ida:GraphScopes` key.

Having said that, to make this request working:

```
public async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{
   return await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("mail").GetAsync();
}
```

you could explicitly update the delegated permissions in web.config:

```
<add key="ida:GraphScopes" value="User.Read User.ReadBasic.All"/>
```

**How to validade access token**

The permissions for access token could be validated via [this](http://calebb.net/) or [this](https://jwt.io) service. Once decoded, delegated permissions are represented via `scp` attribute, for example:

```
scp: "Files.ReadWrite Mail.Send User.Read"
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, I will try this out tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes. Could you please expand on what you mean by "how to validate the token"? Is that something I need to do before I can get it working?

Comment: Regarding access token service, it is not а mandatory, just a supplementary tool for access token verification

Comment: Thank you so much Vadim that seems to have worked - lifesaver